# REVERSE function in LISP

Tags: functional-programming, lisp

Could anybody explain in detail how the following pure LISP function works:

```
(DEFINE (REVERSE (LAMBDA (L)
        (REV NIL L))))
(DEFINE (REV (LAMBDA (OUT IN)
        (COND ((NULL IN) OUT)
        (T (REV (CONS (CAR IN) OUT) (CDR IN))))))
```

The function should reverse the order of the elements in a list, that's clear, but I am still unable to understand how it works.

****EDIT****

okay i believe i figured it out.
The `REVERSE` function is called with a list as argument, and calls a `REV` function with `NIL` and that list `L` as arguments.

**REV**: `OUT` is bound to `NIL` and `IN` is bound to the list `L`.
Now, if the first argument (`IN`) is empty (`NULL`?) we are done and we can return `OUT`, which is the list, successfully reversed. 
Otherwise we have to continue by recursively calling `REV` with `OUT+the first element of IN` as first argument and the `rest of IN` as the second argument. Is this how it works?

The only question is: What's about the `LAMBDA` thing here?

Comment: It's either `(define (name . args) ...)` or `(define name (lambda args ...))`. `(define (name . ((lambda (l) (rev nil l)))) #| no body |# )` won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is how it works. This is known as accumulator argument technique for writing [tail recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion) functions. It helps to visualize its operation with some example, e.g.

```
reverse [1,2,3,4] 
  = rev  NIL  [1,2,3,4]
  = rev  [1]    [2,3,4]
  = rev  [2,1]    [3,4]
  = rev  [3,2,1]    [4]
  = rev  [4,3,2,1]  NIL
  = [4,3,2,1]
```

It seems your code comes from an oldish (1st ed. 1982, ISBN 0-471-08755-6) [textbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471104264). In today's Scheme e.g. it's written almost the same, but without the extra parentheses (with few constants redefined):

```
(define reverse (lambda (l) .... ))
(define rev (lambda (out in) .... ))

(define NIL '())
(define T    #t)
(define NULL null?)
```

The so-called "lambda forms", i.e. forms (well-formed, parenthesized snippets of code) starting with `lambda` "keyword", signify anonymous functions. The list after the symbol `lambda` specifies formal parameters of such function. `define` allows us to name the function created by a lambda-form. That way we can  make recursive call to it inside its definition, using its name.

This recursive call is in [tail position](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), so the operation of this function is equivalent to a loop (achieved by reusing the [stack frame](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_frame#Structure) for the function call, resetting the formal parameters on each iteration  which thus serve as loop variables).

Comment: So the lambda form is a way to handle arguments in LISP, is this correct?

Comment: @user1291235 lambda form is a way to create functions in Lisp.

Comment: Scheme? With NIL and T?

Comment: @uselpa you're right. `define` threw me off I guess. So, what is it?

Comment: @uselpa apparently the code is a verbatim copy from "Programming language concepts. —Third edition. Carlo Ghezzi, Mehdi Jazayeri. John Wiley & Sons"  (1st.ed.1982), http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Language-Concepts-Carlo-Ghezzi/dp/0471104264, p345. The authors call this language "Lisp".

Comment: @WillNess R1RS came in 1985 and Sussman and Abelson called Scheme LISP in 1987 in their SICP videos. It had lots of MacLIPS stuff with lexical scoping so the differences between MacLISP and Scheme was not so great as the differences between CL and Scheme today.

Comment: @Sylwester the question is, does it merit tagging this question as Scheme too? :) (I'm going through the AIM-349 in the other window right now trying to find NIL and T there... so far I've got LABELS...)

Comment: @WillNess Examples in AIM-349 has `NIL` several places. eq. `sqrt` on page 3.

Comment: @Sylwester Bingo! :)  ... and NULL as well. Well, it wasn't even  language back then, just a library on top MacLISP.

Comment: @WillNess I guess this version is so ancient it should not have a scheme tag. In fact it has more in common with LISP1.5

Comment: @Sylwester yes, I was thinking exactly the same thing. Thanks! (it might even not be ancient but just dreamt-up, with that extra level of parentheses... or maybe they did a proprietary implementation...)